# Sorting the json file

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, json-ld

Hi I am working on a project it will show USD EUR TRY Bitcoin Gold values i have api for all of this values in json i want to sort them out my json link is this https://canlidoviz.com/doviz-kurlari.jsonld

I am parsing the json with this class

```
    public class ClassJSONParser {

    private InputStream is = null;
    private JSONObject jObj = null;
    private String json = "";

    public ClassJSONParser(){

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromURL(String url) {
        try {
            URL urlObject = new java.net.URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                String tmp = line + "/n";
                sb.append(tmp);
            }
            is.close();
            json=sb.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Buffer Error","Error Converting Result"+e.toString());
        }

        try {
            if(json !=null){
                jObj=new JSONObject(json);
            }else{
                jObj=null;
            }

        }catch (JSONException e){

        }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

and getting a string like this

```
ClassJSONParser jParser = new ClassJSONParser();
        String url = "https://canlidoviz.com/doviz-kurlari.jsonld";
        jsonO= jParser.getJSONFromURL(url);
        Log.d("***",jsonO.toString());
```

what method should i use how can i do can you give me guidance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You seem to have converted your JSON string into a `JSONObject`, are you looking for help generating objects from that?

Comment: Yep i want to get like name=USD price =8.1152 priceCurrency=TRY i want to crate a list of these

Comment: So a Java object something like `Value(String name, double price, Currency priceCurrency)`?